# Is there metaphorical meaning of "aus der Haft entlassen"?

Tags: idiom

In a formal letter that I received there was a sentence

> Gerne werden wir Sie aus der Haft entlassen per 31.05.2019.

It is regarding rental agreement, but the only translation for *Haft*, that I've found is *prison* and I am not being actually released from prison.

If I search for whole sentence I only find literal meaning. That's why I wonder how to properly translate it.

Is the following translation correct?

> We let you go of any obligation

Comment: Is it possible, that "Haft" is simply an error? Could it be instead "**Haftung**"? This is still weird, but it would be close to your proposal with "obligation".

Comment: It could be meant as a joke.

Comment: Probably a shortened form of "Haftung" (liability)

Comment: Maybe she meant "Haftung", because it is about ending contract.

Comment: It could not be a joke, it is official letter.

Comment: It sounds like someone who didn't speak German used Google Translate to create this document

Comment: She is a native speaker :D So probably typo or autocorrect.

Comment: @MateuszŚwiątkowski Then you should speak with her and clarify if it is a simple error, which should be corrected in the letter.

Comment: Context please. How should we assess if this is a joke, a typo, or simply the correct use of the expression without knowing what the letter is about? - And by the way, why don't you just accept that they let you go from prison?

Comment: Could you please add a location, just in case it's a regional thing?

Comment: @Arsak  Are you thinking of some peculiar use of "Haft" in, say, Austria or Switzerland? These are the only regions I can think of where such gross peculiarities could occur.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Exactly.

Comment: @Arsak
It happened high in the mountains of lovely land of Switzerland.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Because now I need to get food on my own.

Comment: But also in Switzerland, "Haft" seems not to be a usual short form of "Haftung". Swiss right uses normal "Haftung", too.

Comment: Maybe it is a play of words.. if you live somewhere, you are *wohn**haft** in ...*, now that you move out, you're released from your "*Wohn-Haft*"...

Comment: The "Schweizerische Idiotikon" has about 7 pages on "Haft" - I'm sure you'll find a meaning that fits.

Comment: @MateuszŚwiątkowski: Not necessarily autocorrection. You'll see such errors in formal communication too, also from native speakers, although not very often. No one is perfect. I see similar errors in formal English communication too.

Answer (score 13):

For me it sounds like bad German, because I don't know any other meaning of `Haft` than prison.

"Liability" or your "obligation" would fit much butter, because there should be used `Haftung`, while `Haft` is connected to `Verhaftung` as in the same context/ meaning^^.

Comment: Doesn't make sense either. "Aus der Haftung entlassen" is not a thing that one can do "per [date]". Either you are responsible, or you aren't. No date possible. (That's if *Haftung* is really what they mean.)

Comment: One can be "aus der Haftung entlassen werden per Datum", which means that one is no longer responsible for a liability after the specified date.

Answer (score 7):

As you said that this letter is from a Swiss speaker I think this <s>is</s> could be Swiss dialect for "aus der Haftung entlassen am [Datum]", mean your contract ends at this date.

Nevertheless I want to point out, that there can be in fact a metaphorical meaning:
"Haft" can be interpreted as "Geiselhaft" (to held hostage), meaning that you are under some kind of oppression by the other party and this oppression will end.

Comment: Did you find any  dictionary entry or similar that supports the theory that using *Haft* instead of *Haftung* is used in Swiss dialects?

Comment: No, this is just a theory evolving from the fact that the suffix "-ung" is spoken "-ig" in many Swiss dialects. Shorten the word even more leads to completly omitting it. But I am not a native speaker of any Siwss dialect so this is just guessing and linguistic intution based on my expirience with Swiss dialects.

Comment: I have a word in my mind where they actually do that, but I am not getting to it.

Comment: But OP mentions it is a formal writen letter.

Answer (score 4):

Your translation is correct. As @Madjosz already suspected, *Haft*, in *Schweizerdeutsch* [can mean collateral](https://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/id2.htm#!page/21055/mode/1up) (left column, end of second third, fourth meaning). That said, it is not commonly used that way. What @Shegit said still holds true: *Haftung* would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

As a native speaker I can say that there is no metaphorical meaning I know or could think of. "Haft" in context of prison is a legal term and only applies if a judge sentences someone to a kind of incarceration. This only made sence if you were currently in prison and it would never appear in a letter regarding of rental agreements - only in letters from a court, judge or possibly lawyer.

Like almost every word, "Haft" can have different meanings depending on the context. It can mean "imprisonment", "liability" or "adhesion". It can't be the legal term that means "incarceration" (since you can't be released from prison if you are not in prison) and it is obviously not "adhesion" so the only possible meaning is "liability" even though that is i.m.o. the least common one and is more likely to be translated as "Haftung" (Though it is correct to use "liability" for "Haft" and vice versa). It is the only meaning that makes any sence here.

You propably asked to terminate the rental agreement and they agreed and clarified the date when the liabilities end.

No metaphore, just uncommon wording and the mutual agreement not to continue the rental agreement after 2019-05-31.

Comment: And we all know how uncommon the language of official documents can be sometimes.

Comment: I know different meaning of `Haft` only dependent from pre and post syllables. After that comes the context. Like `verhaftet werden` vs. `xxx verhaftet sein`. So I am different opinion on parts of your answer, like `Haft` can mean liability or adhesion. That is in my opinion reserved to `Haftung` only.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Pre and post syllables don't change the meaning of the word, they create a new word with the same radical/ word stem. Just type in "Haft" in any tranflator or look it up in any dictionary and you'll see that there are mulitble meanings. As a native speaker I often times don't know the exact rules but I DO know how the language works. Pre and post syllables change the word, inherit the meaning and give context to it.

Btw. "Haftung" and "ver-" make "Verhaftung", whitch means detention again. The rdical "Haft" has three possible meanings depending on word formation and context.

Comment: @hajef: Zwar gibt es Metaphern die so häufig verwendet werden, dass der unmetaphorische Gebrauch hervorgehoben werden muss (Gang nach Canossa), aber es gibt keine Liste von Metaphern. Ein Wort ist eine Metapher, wenn es jemand als Metapher verwendet. Jedes Wort kann metaphorisch verwendet werden.

Comment: After looking up different dictionaries I find for the specific `Haft` as a noun only different meaning after adding pre- and post syllables. The linking between jail and adhesion I see only in the metaphorical of the stem "when you are in jail, you stay there longer = when you are glued to sth you stick to it longer" https://de-en.dict.cc/?s=haft https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/haft https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=haft&l=deen&in=&lf=de&qnac=# https://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/dings.cgi?service=deen&opterrors=0&optpro=0&query=haft&iservice=

Comment: @ShegitBrahm interesting to see how you don't reply to anything I saied but prove things wrong that I didn't say xD

I saied that "the radical "Haft" has three different meanings" you can find in any dictionary. As I pointed out in my answer, "Haft" is a legal term and officially means nothing else. But since the radical has multible meanings, in natural language, there might be occasions where the word "Haft" refers to one of the other meanings of the radical - but again, as pointed out, other usages of the noun "Haft" itself are rare.

Answer (score 1):

In (parts of) Switzerland, *Haft* can also mean *Pflicht*. This gets us to *jdn. aus der Pflicht entlassen*, and we may read:

> *Gerne werden wir Sie aus dem Vertrag entlassen.*

As far as I understand it, that's what it's all about.

Comment: Is there any chance you've found a dictionary entry that support this usage or maybe examples from Swiss newspaper articles or similar?

Comment: Yes, there is a chance. :-) *Haft* in the meaning of *Pflicht* can be found in **Schweizer Idiotikon**, https://idiotikon.ch/online-woerterbuch

Comment: please edit your answer and add it there. It will improve your post and makes sure the information doesn't get lost when the comments will be deleted